# Emit websocket message from a view

Tags: python, flask, flask-sockets

I am playing around with websockets in order to see if I can replace polling updates to a project. I am using Flask-Sockets and I want to emit an update through a Flask view.

For example

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send(message)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    # here I want to emit a message like ws.send(message)
    return 'Hello World!'
```

I looked around and I didnt find anything similar. Is this thing possible?

Comment: Ever found an answer? I'm looking for this too

Comment: Sadly I didn't. I decided to use Server Sent Events as websockets wasn't what I needed.

Comment: I got an answer here :) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47526225/111510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS IS VERY VERY SIMPLE DEMO EXAMPLE**

In the below example, on every 2 seconds, the server send message to the client with updated count. First parameter of emit function tells which function to call on client side.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
thread = None


def background_thread():
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(2)
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Message from server', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)
    emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

On your client side you will have to use [this](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js). In this example I have included CDN. Similarly for demo purpose I have used jquery.

**templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask-SocketIO Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            namespace = '/test';
            var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
            // This will be called by server.
            // Anonymous function will be executed and span with id "view" will be updated
            socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
                $('span#view').text(msg.count);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO Simple Example</h1>
    <p>Counter at server: <span id="view"></span></p>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run this using `python app.py`, and visit http://127.0.0.1:5050, then you should see the sockets in action.

A working version of the demo is available [here](https://github.com/nabinkhadka/simple-flask-socket)