# Listening socket clients in background and send data from web page to the clients in Python

Tags: python, sockets, flask, tcp, embedded

I have I/O controller (which can turn on/off the lights) connect to the server (digitalocean running on ubuntu) using TCP/IP protocol. I/O controller acts as a client. I have python script listening connections from clients. This python script path **/root/tcp_socket/server_socket.py**

> server_socket.py

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR
import _thread
import time
import datetime

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8080
buf = 1024

addr = (host, port)

serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversocket.bind(addr)
serversocket.listen(10)

clients = [serversocket]


def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    print("Accepted connection from: ", clientaddr)
    while True:
         data = clientsocket.recv(1024)

while True:
   try:
       print("Server is listening for connections\n")
       clientsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
       clients.append(clientsocket)
       _thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsocket, clientaddr))
   except KeyboardInterrupt: 
       print("Closing server socket...")
       serversocket.close()
```

I have web site which is built on **python Flask** framework running on ubuntu. In my website has toggle buttons such as turn on and turn off.
[Turn on and turn off toggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMCcU.png). **path /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/**

My question is how can I access from web page to connected clients which can handle by using **server_socket.py**.And how can I send **"On" command to the I/O controller** when on toggle clicked

Comment: You need to send a string for toggle on and off perhaps 1 and 0 would work. And then you can peform your task.

Comment: Ok how can I send to client ? client.send(b"1") i know this one. But how can I get "client" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693763/emit-websocket-message-from-a-view/46256698#46256698